# multiple windowed counts with distinct user_id

Tags: postgresql

Given an `event` table, I want to find the count of distinct `user_id`s for a specific event `type` in four different windows:

- past 365 days
- past 30 days
- past 7 days
- current day

I came up with this idea of a query (non-working), which probably shows best what I try to accomplish:

```
select
  d as "Date",
  count(distinct user_id) over (
    order by d
    rows between 365 preceding and current row
  ) "Yearly Active",
  count(distinct user_id) over (
    order by d
    rows between 30 preceding and current row
  ) "Monthly Active",
  count(distinct user_id) over (
    order by d
    rows between 7 preceding and current row
  ) "Weekly Active",
  count(distinct user_id) as "Daily Active"
from (
  select
    date(to_timestamp(event_time/1000) at time zone 'Europe/Berlin') d,
    user_id
  from event_entity
  where type = 'REFRESH_TOKEN'
  group by 1, user_id
  order by d
) daily_users
```

But we cannot use `distinct` in window functions. What is a better approach to the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach to this query is not using window functions, you can get the data you need just by using non-windowed `count` and `case when` statements.
First get all distinct date and user_id values in a CTE and all distinct dates in another CTE

```
WITH daily_users AS(
    select distinct
    date(to_timestamp(event_time/1000) at time zone 'Europe/Berlin') d,
    user_id
    from event_entity
    where type = 'REFRESH_TOKEN'
),
all_dates AS(
   select distinct
   date(to_timestamp(event_time/1000) at time zone 'Europe/Berlin') d
   from event_entity
   where type = 'REFRESH_TOKEN'
)
```

Join the dates with the daily_users cte, then use the a `CASE` statement inside the `COUNT`, replacing `user_id` with `NULL` for all dates outside the relevant range:

```
select all_dates.d as "date",
    --daily
    count(distinct case when all_dates.d = daily_users.d then daily_users.user_id else null end) as daily_active,
    --weekly
    count(distinct case when all_dates.d - daily_users.d < 7 then daily_users.user_id else null end) as weekly_active,
    --30 days
    count(distinct case when all_dates.d - daily_users.d < 30 then daily_users.user_id else null end) as monthly_active,
    --yearly, just count distinct user_id because the 365 day condition is already provided by the join
    count(distinct daily_users.user_id) as yearly_active
from all_dates
inner join daily_users on all_dates.d >= daily_users.d and (all_dates.d - daily_users.d < 365) --filter only rows between the date in all_dates and one year before
group by all_dates.d
```

Some notes:

- `count` ignores null values, that's why the `case` expressions set user_id to null in all rows outside the relevant period
- in postgres, subtracting two dates returns an integer equal to the number of days between the two dates

Comment: interesting approach, do I understand the inner join correctly? It joins data per year and the counts then split that yearly-data into other chunks (daily, weekly etc) - correct? So it will shows multiple years in the result.

Comment: The inner join is used to join each date in "all_dates" with all records between that date and one year before that (which is the largest period you're interested in); after the GROUP BY there will be one record for each date, showing the daily/weekly/monthly/yearly unique users. The CASE statements are only used to count distinct user_id in the relevant period (1,7,30,365 days)

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

If you want to use the windows function, you can use a trick. You can use the bellow formula to remove duplicate `user_id`:

```
abs(
  dense_rank() over (order by d, user_id)
  - dense_rank() over (order by d, user_id DESC)
  + 1
)
```

But I don't know the result of the query it is the same you expected.

Please check this structure. Is this query has resulted in what you expect?

```sql
select distinct on (d)
  d,
  ----
  abs(
    dense_rank() over asc_total_preceding
    - dense_rank() over desc_total_preceding
  ) + 1 as "Daily Active",
  ----
  abs(
    dense_rank() over asc_7_preceding
    - dense_rank() over desc_7_preceding
  ) + 1 as "Weekly Active",
  ----
  abs(
    dense_rank() over asc_30_preceding
    - dense_rank() over desc_30_preceding
  ) + 1 as "Monthly Active",
 ----
  abs(
    dense_rank() over asc_365_preceding
    - dense_rank() over desc_365_preceding
  ) + 1 as "Yearly Active"
from (
  select
    date(to_timestamp(event_time/1000) at time zone 'Europe/Berlin') d,
    user_id
  from event_entity
  where type = 'REFRESH_TOKEN'
  group by 1, user_id
  order by d
) daily_users
window
  asc_total_preceding as (order by d, user_id),
  desc_total_preceding as (order by d, user_id),
  asc_7_preceding as (order by d, user_id rows between 7 preceding and current row),
  desc_7_preceding as (order by d, user_id desc rows between 7 preceding and current row),
  asc_30_preceding as (order by d, user_id rows between 30 preceding and current row),
  desc_30_preceding as (order by d, user_id desc rows between 30 preceding and current row),
  asc_365_preceding as (order by d, user_id rows between 365 preceding and current row),
  desc_365_preceding as (order by d, user_id desc rows between 365 preceding and current row)
```

---

P.S (Old query)

In my opinion, better to change the query structure and use `group by` and `filter` to calculate the count of users on each date

```sql
select
  d as "Date",
  count(distinct user_id) filter (
    where d between current_date - 365 and current_date
  ) as "Yearly Active",
  count(distinct user_id) filter (
    where d between current_date - 30 and current_date
  ) as "Monthly Active",
  count(distinct user_id) filter (
    where d between current_date - 7 and current_date
  ) as "Weekly Active",
  count(distinct user_id) filter (
    where d = current_date
  ) as "Daily Active"
from (
  select
    date(to_timestamp(event_time/1000) at time zone 'Europe/Berlin') d,
    user_id
  from event_entity
  where type = 'REFRESH_TOKEN'
  group by 1, user_id
  order by d
) daily_users
group by d
```

Comment: this only gives the counts for a single date/week/month/year and not windowed. The result should have the values for all dates of all times where on each day the last day/week/month/year is included.

Comment: Please check new query with windows function and send feedback about the query @Stuck

Comment: Thanks for the re-try. It still does not work. E.g. it now shows a 1 for "Daily Active" on all days, but there exist multiple different users with a refresh token per day.